# Como enviar comandos SMTP e o IP não ser bloqueado?

Tags: php, ip, smtp

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em PHP que envia comandos SMTP para validação de e-mail, mas o problema é que em alguns provedores o meu IP é adicionado em blacklist. Tem alguma forma de resolver isso?

Para validar estou enviando alguns comando por socket:

```
HELO dominio.com.br
FROM: <usuario@dominio.com.br>
RCPT TO:<usuario@dominio.com.br>
```

Utilizando os comandos acima consigo pegar varias mensagens do sistema.

Comment: Quais são estes comandos? Fica difícil responder assim porque não dá para saber exatamente o que você está fazendo de errado.

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Comment: Parece que depende da quantidade de consultas que você faz por servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Seu ip esta entrando em blacklist porque o provedor de destino esta detectando uma atividade em massa incomum junto ao seu ip local, tente definir um limite bem mais baixo para as consultas e verificações, algo em torno de 20 à 50 por hora deverá resolver seu problema se tratando de uma validação com sintax MX apenas.